# Missing link in Wikipedia's proof of quadratic reciprocity law

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, quadratic-residues, quadratic-reciprocity

Gauss' well-known law of quadratic reciprocity states the following:

> **Main Theorem.** Given two disttinct primes, $p$ and $q$, if at least one of $p-1$ and $q-1$ is divisable by $4$, then the congruency $x^2 \equiv q ~\operatorname{mod} p$ is solvable iff $x^2 \equiv p ~\operatorname{mod} q$ is. But if $p\equiv q \equiv 3 \operatorname{mod} 4$, then  $x^2 \equiv q ~\operatorname{mod} p$ is solvable iff $x^2 \equiv -p ~\operatorname{mod} q$ is. Using the [Legandre symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol), it can be stated simply as $\left({\frac {p}{q}}\right)\left({\frac {q}{p}}\right)=(-1)^{{\frac {p-1}{2}}{\frac {q-1}{2}}}$.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_reciprocity#Proofs_of_the_supplements) provides a short proof, originally by [B. Veklych [2019]](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.08121). They first prove some sort of lemma:

> **Lemma.** Let $p$ be an odd prime. Thus $2$ is a quadratic residue iff the number of solutions to the equation $x^2 +y^2 = 2$ in $\Bbb{F}_p$ is divisable by $8$.

Afterwards, they prove that the number of solutions to this equation can by expressed by
${\displaystyle p-(-1)^{\frac {p-1}{2}}}$. They finish the proof by stating:

*"Therefore, $2$ is a residue modulo $p$ if and only if $8$ divides ${\displaystyle p-(-1)^{\frac {p-1}{2}}}$. This is a reformulation of the condition stated above."*

> **Question.** *Why* is this a reformulation of the main threom's statement?

Comment: It's clearly not a restatement of the Main Theorem, but it is a restatement of the Lemma.

Comment: @lulu How is this re-stating the lemma? It uses the lemma and counts the number of solutions to the equation differently. Also, why would they prove the lemma once more?

Comment: It's just a reformulation.  If you have proved that the number of solutions to the given equation is the given  function of $p$, then you can substitute that function for the number of solutions.  I don't think it's intended to be an especially deep remark.

Comment: @lulu So where's the proof of the theorem? I don't understand

Comment: I don't understand your confusion.  The argument by Veklech that you link to is clearly referred to as a proof of one of the supplements. That's all you get out of that argument.

Comment: @lulu I don't understand what supplement and how they are used in the proof.

Comment: Perhaps Wikipedia is not the best source for you here...Quadratic Reciprocity is one of the most important results in elementary Number Theory, any reference will go over it in depth.  Wikipedia is intended to be very terse, and that is obviously confusing to you.  If you insist on sticking with it, note that the page clearly refers to two Supplements to the main theorem, concerning $-1$ and $\pm 2$.  The argument you link to addresses the case of $2$.  That is very clearly stated on the page in question.

Comment: The page also clearly refers you to a [second page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_quadratic_reciprocity) wherein the Main Theorem is proven.